# after adding integer to a string get an error when using it in class

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

```
import pigpio
import time
pi = pigpio.pi()
L1 = 2
L2 = 3
L3 = 4
L4 = 17
L5 = 27
L6 = 22
L7 = 10
R1 = 9
R2 = 18
R3 = 23
R4 = 24
R5 = 25
R6 = 8
R7 = 7
On = 255
Off = 0
sleepTime = 0.05
class ledControll:
    def pinClean(self):
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(L1 , Off)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(L2 , Off)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(L3 , Off)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(L4 , Off)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(L5 , Off)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(L6 , Off)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(L7 , Off)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(R1 , Off)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(R2 , Off)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(R3 , Off)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(R4 , Off)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(R5 , Off)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(R6 , Off)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(R7 , Off)  
    def LEDOn(self , column , rows):
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(column , On)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(rows , On)
    def LEDOff(self , column , row):
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(column , Off)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(row , Off)
try:
    led = ledControll()
    while True:
        for i in range(1 , 7):
            row = "R" + str(i)
            led.LEDOn(L1 , row)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    led.pinClean()
pi.stop()
```

this is my code in python, when i run this i get this error:
struct.error: cannot convert argument to integer
i want to set R1 to R7 with for in led.LEDOn(L1 , R1 to R7)
and when i print row it gives me R1 to R7
i'm new in python

Comment: It seems that `def LEDOn(self , column , rows):`  requires 3 parameters and you're using only 2. `led.LEDOn(L1 , row)`

Comment: @mcNets, no, that's normal. The `self` argument is supplied implicitly when doing a method call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 2):

`row = "R" + str(i)` doesn't cause `row` to refer to any of your variables whose name starts with "R". You're effectively doing `led.LEDOn(L1, "R1")` when you need to be doing `led.LEDOn(L1, R1)`.

You might be thinking, "OK, so how do I get a variable, given a string containing its name?" This is covered in detail in the question [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/953482), but the short answer is: don't have a bunch of variables that differ only by a number; use a dictionary or list instead.

In your specific case, you might do something like

```
Rs = [9, 18, 23, 24, 25, 8, 7]
```

At the top of your file, then

```
for R in Rs:
    led.LEDOn(L1, R)
```

In your function.

This has the additional benefit of making your `pinClean` method a lot shorter, too:

```
def pinClean(self):
    for L in Ls:
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(L, Off)
    for R in Rs:
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(R, Off)
```

(... Provided you also decide to make your L variables into a list)

Comment: Hello @Root, if this answer helped and solved your question please set it as the answer for this question. Have a nice day!